# Issue in Jenkins integration with GitHub and Ionic project

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to integrate ionic application with Jenkins and i am using GitHub as a repository. When i run the Multibranch pipeline job manually, the Jenkin is displaying below error.

Does anyone know what can be possible issue ? I am trying to learn how CI/CD works with this demo experiment.

I am referring this Youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5voVJb3rHI&t=605s

```
Started by user admin
13:42:45 Connecting to https://api.github.com using PrashobThekkyal/*****
Obtained Jenkinsfile from a85fffb01a96c5c5d550326873047c6071557aff
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:146)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.reader(ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.TypeHierarchyReader.hierarchyOf(TypeHierarchyReader.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.hierarchyOf(ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.java:39)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.TypeHierarchyReader$TypeHierarchy.isAssignableFrom(TypeHierarchyReader.java:321)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.TypeHierarchyReader$TypeHierarchy.isAssignableFromAnyInterfaceImplementedBy(TypeHierarchyReader.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.TypeHierarchyReader$TypeHierarchy.isAssignableFrom(TypeHierarchyReader.java:311)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.TypeHierarchyReader.isAssignableFrom(TypeHierarchyReader.java:124)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.isAssignableFrom(ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.java:39)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.TypeHierarchyReader.getCommonSuperClass(TypeHierarchyReader.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.helper.ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.getCommonSuperClass(ClassLoadingReferenceTypeHierachyReader.java:39)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.NonClassLoadingClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(NonClassLoadingClassWriter.java:72)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.SymbolTable.addMergedType(SymbolTable.java:1209)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1293)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1238)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1604)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1540)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:807)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.commons.JSRInlinerAdapter.visitEnd(JSRInlinerAdapter.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.Transformer$1$1.visitEnd(Transformer.java:109)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(MethodVisitor.java:783)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1278)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:679)
    at org.kohsuke.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
    at org.jenkinsci.bytecode.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:115)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:706)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1363)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.<init>(CpsScript.java:69)
    at WorkflowScript.<init>(WorkflowScript)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:434)
Caused: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class WorkflowScript. Reason
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:466)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {

            steps {
                echo "Building Multibranch Pipeline"
            }
        }

        stage ('Testing') {

            steps {
                echo "Testing Multibranch Pipeline"
            }
        }


        stage ('Deployment') {
            steps {                
                echo "False Deploying Multibranch Pipeline"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Jenkins Job configuration:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of analysis finally I have found the solution. I have did a very basic mistake of not reading version requirement to run Jenkins.

[Java requirement to run Jenkins job](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/#running-jenkins)

As mentioned in above URL, under the section 'Running Jenkins', they have clearly mentioned the support versions of java to run Jenkins job. So I checked java version and it was running on **Java 13-a**, yes that was stupid, because the Jenkins job will only run with java version 8 and 11.

So degrade your java version to 8 or 11 and it will work smoothly.

**Proof**
[image]

I thought to delete my stupid question, but later I thought to keep it, if in case it could help somebody. Kindly please don't give any kind of (+ve or -vew) points to this post, as it doesn't make any sense.